# Images is not working Xamarin Cross

Tags: ios, image, xamarin.forms

I add many image (png) to resource (both Android and IOS) and call that in my code. But when I deploy, the image not showing. I try to use the default image (icon.png) and it show.  the image that I add to resource doesn't show in that file. Please help.

Comment: Just Click on Show all files from solution explorer you will see the images that you were added to Resource folder. Select that image & Right click on it you will see "Include in Project" option click on it. then run your project

Comment: Option1: Make sure you have included image in resource folder by right click on image and selecting Include, If you have added image from outside the project. Option2: Remove existing image from folder and add it from project again by right click on Resource-> add existing item->add your image.

Answer (score 1):

Just Click on Show all files from solution explorer you will see the images that you were added to Resource folder.

[image]

Select that image & Right click on it you will see "Include in Project" option click on it. then run your project